# save data from javascript form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

***********EDIT ************

This is now my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
$(".div2").append("<div class='tekst2'><div id='green'></div><textarea rows='8' cols='30' id='tekst' name='tekst' class='tekst'></textarea></div><br/>");
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
$(".div3").append("<div class='tekst'><div id='red'></div><input class='nummer' id='nummer' type='text' name='nummer'></div><br/>");
});

var ele = new Array();
$("#btn1").click(function(){
$('.tekst').each(function(){
$('.nummer').each(function(){
ele.push($(this).val());

}); });
var send = ele.join(',')
request = $.ajax({
url: "form.php",
type: "post",
data: ele
//you can use this request object to know what's the status of your response
});
});

});
</script>
```

And this is the code for set the data to the database

```
 <?php
 require_once'config.php';
 $tekst      = $_GET['tekst'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO draaiboek (tekst) 
                    VALUES ('$tekst')";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


 if($result) {

 } 
 else {

  }
```

Only i get empty rows in the database. Whats gone wrong?

**********END EDIT**************

I made a site to fill things in on an form. I have two buttons to get an extra form field on the screen. I want to save the data using the exact same markup somewhere. In a mysql database or locally. Does anyone know how you can store data and can later read out again with the same format? This is the code for get an extra form field:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnAddtoList').click(function(){
        var newDiv = $('<div class="tekst2"><div id="green"></div><input class="formtijd" placeholder="Tijd" id="tijd" type="text" name="tijd"><textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="tekst" name="tekst" class="tekst"></textarea></div><br/>');
        //newDiv.style.background = "#000";
        $('body').append(newDiv);
    });
    $('#btnAddtoList2').click(function(){
        var newDiv = $('<div class="tekst"><div id="red"></div><input class="formtijd" placeholder="Tijd" id="tijd" type="text" name="tijd"><input class="formtekst" id="nummer" type="text" name="nummer"></div><br/>');
        //newDiv.style.background = "#000";
        $('body').append(newDiv);
    });
});
```

And this is the code for show on the screen:

```
 <button id="btnAddtoList" class="btn btn-success">Nieuw tekst veld</button>
 <button id="btnAddtoList2" class="btn btn-danger">Nieuw nummer veld</button><br/><br/>

 <div id="tekst"></div>
 <div id="tekst2"></div>
```

When I click on the button, there shows an new field. So it looks like: 
[image]

Comment: You can use **JavaScript** cookies?

Comment: If you are going to click these buttons `multiple times`, then declaring an `Array` will solve your problem

Comment: Can you show your backend php code that saves your data inside a mysql database? And where does the data get posted to the backend? If locally suffices, cookies can be a solution indeed. But if you need any persistent data the end user can't delete, save it in a database.

Comment: I dont have the code for save data to the database because I am watching what is the most convenient feature. When you save the layout is not included in the database. And I want to do that. Exactly the same format as I production. If I click on the button will always create the same div. I could change that it: text1, text2, text3 etc become?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be not an efficient one but this is what I could write in short time

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("div").append("<input type='text' class='funfoo' placeholder='Fill me'/> <br/><br/>");
});
   var ele = new Array();
   $("#btn1").click(function(){
   $('.funfoo').each(function(){
   ele.push($(this).val());

   });
   var send = ele.join(',')
    request = $.ajax({
    url: "/form.php",
    type: "post",
    data: ele
   //you can use this request object to know what's the status of your response
});
});

});
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <button id="btn">Add fields</button>
    <button id="btn1">Submit fields</button>
    <div></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In this approach, you can simply append input values and then get all the values in them. Join all the values with comma and then dump in any single column (will save lot of other effort and you just need one column for all the values).

Now to display these values in the same format what you can do is, simply get the field value form DB, split them and add input fields for individual values. (you can do it in a loop I'll show you a demo).

```
--------------------------your display page --------------

//this is a pseudo code
<?php
$val = query to get that value (comma separated)from db
$val2 = $val.split(',');
for($i =0; $i<val2.lenght; $i++)
{
<input class='' value='<?php echo $val2[i] ?>'/>
}
?>
```

Hope this would help you :)

Comment: This is the code for show the values from the database.  <?php
 $val = 'SELECT tekst FROM draaiboek WHERE id = $id';
 $val2 = $val.split(',');
 for($i =0; $i<val2.lenght; $i++)
 { ?>
 <input class='nummer' value='<?php echo $val2[i] ?>'/>
 <?php } ?> But he didn't show something. Whats gone wrong?

Comment: **there you go **

<?php
 `$val = `mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query(your_db_connection_object,'SELECT tekst FROM draaiboek WHERE id = $id'))`;
`$val2 = ($val->tekst).split(',')` ;

`for($i =0; $i<val2.lenght; $i++) { ?> <input class='nummer' value='<?php echo $val2[i] ?>'/>`

?>

Comment: I get this errors: Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home/.....

Warning: split() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/.....

Notice: Use of undefined constant val2 - assumed 'val2' in /home/.....

Notice: Use of undefined constant lenght - assumed 'lenght' in /home/....

Comment: try this
$val2 = explode(", ", $val->tekst);
foreach($val2 as $val22) {

    <input class='nummer' value='<?php echo $val22 ?>'/>
  
}